# How to set the ery globap $PATH in Ubuntu 10.04 Server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, environment-variables, path, ubuntu-10.04

On Ubuntu 10.04 Server, where can I adjust the essential $PATH environment variable value which will all applications and all users see?

Answer (score 3):

/etc/profile is probably the closest you'll come. Some (users|applications) may of course be setting their own PATH, and there's nothing you can do about this.

Comment: But there are no initial $PATH settings in /etc/profile by default, and neither are in /etc/bash.bashrc. Where are the initial defalut PATHs set?

Comment: /etc/login.defs

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 10.4...but not the server, I changed /etc/environment